# Hidden scrollbars in Firefox (allows scrolling but just no scrollbar)

Tags: css, firefox, scrollbar

I'd like to create a div that is able to scroll but does not display scrollbars.  I have found a solution for Webkit (below) but how can this be done in other browsers?

I'd prefer to avoid using a javascript plugin.  Hoping to find a CSS or vendor specific solution.

---

## Webkit Solution

```
#photoreel::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
#photoreel {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You must wrap your scrollable div in another div with `overflow:hidden` that hides the scrollbar.

See http://jsfiddle.net/qqPcb/ for an example.

BTW: The same technique is used by [a nice little jQuery plugin called jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/scroll_on_left.html)

Comment: As is shown there, the scrollable div is wider than the wrapper div. However, that also assumes a (max) width of the scroll bar. That width depends on OS, browser and user settings so it might not be safe to assume that any width will cause the scroll bar to disappear without making any content disappear.

Comment: @Arjan That can be easily solved introducing another wrapper div like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/2E4Jg/ (or by detecting the scroll bar width using a couple of lines of JS)

Comment: However, I'm not sure if it's possible to make it work with dynamically sized divs

Comment: Try your demo in Chrome/Safari: highlight/select the first line (foo) and drag your mouse to the right and you'll see the scrollbar. Or use a textarea instead of the inner div and then fill it with some text. Then use the keyboard keys `Page Up` and `Page Down`.

Answer (score 11):

**2019 solution**

Since Firefox 64 there is a perfectly simple solution for this (working only in Firefox and Firefox mobile)

```
scrollbar-width: none;
```

Check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width)

For the comers from the post marked as [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725112/hiding-the-scroll-bar-in-ms-edge-and-firefox), there is also MS Edge solution:

```
-ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
```

Answer (score 1):

For (pre-Chromium) *Edge*:
`-ms-overflow-style: none;`

For *Firefox*:
`scrollbar-width: none;`

Answer (score 0):

> scrollbar-width:none

Applied to the body or the element with scroll bar.

> Overflow:hidden

also disables the scrolling function (makes content not scrollable)

Answer (score -19):

well, there`s a much more easy way! just put

```
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    height: 10px;
    }
```

in your css style and you're done with!

Comment: He's looking for help with Firefox, not Webkit