# How Can I scroll through a div without the scrollbars showing?

Tags: css

I have the following css but the scroll bars are visible. how can I make them invisible (scrollable div without scrollbars)?

```
.myDiv
{
    height:300px;
    overflow: scroll;

}
```

Comment: if you disable the scrollbar, you need something else that can scroll it, otherwise it will not scroll.

Comment: Almost the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820304

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
.myDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height:300px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 183px;
  height: 283px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="myDiv">
    floating div content...
  </div>
</div>
```

This might work - basically you're placing a smaller div around the one you want and hiding the scroll bars.

Comment: Try your demo in Chrome/Safari: highlight/select a line and drag your mouse to the right and you'll see the scrollbar. Or use a textarea instead of the inner div and then fill it with some text. Then use the keyboard keys Page Up and Page Down.

Comment: I like it. Slightly tweaked example in js-fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nCvMc/ works nicely with scrolling mouse or arrow keys.