# jQuery: How do I scroll the body without showing the scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm trying to hide the scroll bar of the document (in some browsers it's the body element, in others it's the html element) by using `overflow:hidden;`. Then i'm using jQuery.animate() to try and animate the scrollTop property. It works fine when the scroll bar is visible (i.e. without the `overflow:hidden;` style) but doesn't work when the scroll bar is hidden. Why is that? I'll be able to post a link to a snapshot of the problematic page in a bit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try make `<body>` `overflow:hidden` and animate the `margin-top` property, note the `margin-top` should be **negative** if you want a positive scrollTop.

On webkit you could use `::-webkit-scrollbar: { display: none; }` to hide the scrollbar with scroll features enabled.

Comment: Seems like the only way (besides in Chrome) is to hack it using margins. Thanks!

Comment: speaking of hacking with margins, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872194/how-can-i-scroll-through-a-div-without-the-scrollbars-showing