# Scroll inside a div with overflow using jquery (or javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with a fixed height and overflow-y : scroll which I am loading via ajax. I'm currently looking for a possibility to scroll the content inside the div (using the mouse wheel) but without displaying the scroll bar. Can anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548072/building-scrollable-div-without-scrollbar

Comment: You can easily achieve this playing with another parent DIV with `overflow:hidden;` just hiding the scrollbars beneath the right edge

Comment: yes, thank you. I would've never tought at this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to use jquery.mousewheel : https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel

On mouse wheel, compute scroll urself :

```
$('.toScroll').on('mousewheel',function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY){
    if(!$(this).attr('data-scrolltop')){
        $(this).attr('data-scrolltop',0);
    }
    var scrollTop = parseInt($(this).attr('data-scrolltop'));
    scrollTop += (-deltaY * lineHeight);
    $(this).attr('data-scrolltop',scrollTop);
    $(this).scrollTop(scrollTop);
});
```

I made a Fiddle as a demonstration :
http://jsfiddle.net/W2pZB/

The only problem is about the var-fixed line height.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by  applying `overflow:hidden` and after  `display-none` on the `scroll-bar` using `css`

And here you can find a same thing in below question .

[jQuery: How do I scroll the body without showing the scroll bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170395/jquery-how-do-i-scroll-the-body-without-showing-the-scroll-bar)

Comment: as @jay suggested you can find a working fiddle also .. cheers :)