# Scrollable div without scrollbars

Tags: html, css

I want make scrollable DIV's but I dont want see scrollbars. Mac OS 10.7-8 have no visible scroll's but other OS (Windows, Mac OS, Linux) have scrolls. How can I make scrollalbe div's without scrollbars?

jsfiddle.net/rGYLh/

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872194/how-can-i-scroll-through-a-div-without-the-scrollbars-showing?rq=1

Comment: I know this "fix", but I would prefer other. Maybe jquery script make this automatic?

Comment: I was looking for this some time ago and @Sgoldy anwser is the best u can get in css. I got some idea right now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's example for on [my Server](http://revelier.home.pl/_examples/StackScrollerExample/) you it work by nicescroll plugin that change css scroll on customized scroll in jQuery. I did cursor width: 0 as u will see in code so scroll dissapear. Btw this plugin works also on  and works perfect on mobile devices etc. Hope it helps :)