# Tricky CSS scroll length

Tags: css, scroll, overflow, positioning

```
<div class="container1"></div>
<div class="container2"><div class="container2-inner"></div></div>

.container1 { height: 5000px; }
.container2 { height: 100%; width: 100%; position:absolute; }
.container2-inner { height: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

`.container2-inner` height varies depending on content inside (`.container2` is overlay popup window).

Currently the vertical browser scroll is always 5000px no matter what OR more if `.container2-inner` exceeds 5000px. I'd like scroll to be only 1000px when popup window is active but I still want to keep 5000px high `.container1` below. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand your problem either based on your description but maybe something like...

CSS

```
HTML, BODY {padding:0;margin:0;}
.container1 {height:5000px;background:red;}
.container2 {height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;background:green}
.container2-inner {height:1000px;width:400px;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:scroll; margin:0 auto;background:yellow}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container1"></div>
<div class="container2">
    <div class="container2-inner">
    Start Here<br />
    ...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />
    ...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />
    ...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />
    ...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />
    ...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />
    ...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />
    ...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />
    ...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />
    ...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />
    ...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />
    ...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />
    ...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />...<br />
    End Here
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see the results at http://dabblet.com/gist/2876726

Comment: Yes, almost there :) I just don't want double scroll (the one for body should scroll yellow area). Is that possible?

Comment: Well...nothing elegant and really I'm not sure you would want to do that for usability concerns, but just for fun... http://dabblet.com/gist/2877502. It is pretty hacky and has limitations.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for :) Now I see some CSS limitations that kept me from achieving something I wanted. Thank you for both solutions!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understood your problem correctly.

You can achieve inner scroll of a modal by using.

```
overflow:scroll
```

But it doesn't work in all browsers.

I found this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqPcb/) on other [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820304/hidden-scrollbars-in-firefox-allows-scrolling-but-just-no-scrollbar) that might help you.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="scroller">
     </div>
</div>​

#wrapper {
    width: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#scroller {
    width: 170px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Thank you Pumbaa80.
Here you can see giving #scroller 20px more than #wrapper you can achieve scroll effect without the Scroll Bar.

Comment: Thank you! Actually all answers posted here are useful for me :) Each one provides some sort of solution including this one.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want .container2 to be a modal popup?
Try to set `overflow:hidden` on the body, when the popup is active, and remove it when it's closed.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want but there's one problem if I do that... I can't scroll that popup using body's scrollbar. I don't want to second container have inner scrollbar only for that popup. Thanks for your response :)

Comment: Then you should give .container1 a parent div with height:100% and set the `overflow:hidden` to this div.

Comment: Thank you! Actually all answers posted here are useful for me :) Each one provides some sort of solution including this one. I consider this problem solved. Thank you again!