# Webkit: Hide vertical scrollbar. Works in Chrome & Safari not in Firefox

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hidden scrollbars in Firefox (allows scrolling but just no scrollbar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820304/hidden-scrollbars-in-firefox-allows-scrolling-but-just-no-scrollbar)

This works fine in Chrome and Safari:

```
iframe::-webkit-scrollbar
{  
    display: none;
}
```

But the vertical scrollbar does not hide in Firefox.

I cannot change the iframe code so needs to be purely in CSS.

**UPDATE:** I added the following along with the above to solve the problem. Both blocks are required:

```
iframe
{  
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

However, this approach will likely constrain my ability to granularly control x or y scrollbars elsewhere.

Oh, well.

Comment: you are telling to hide `scrollbar` only to safari and chrome. Use `-moz-` prefix for mozzila or without prefix

Comment: This has been asked before... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820304/hidden-scrollbars-in-firefox-allows-scrolling-but-just-no-scrollbar

Comment: @morpheus Do you mean this: iframe::-moz-scrollbar
{  
    display: none;
} because that does not solve the problem.

Comment: @Buggabill Thanks, but the answer is not in there. I cannot add classes or wrappers to the iframe as stated above.

Comment: @Buggabill Don't mark the question as a duplicate. I mentioned early on when you answered that the issue was different.

Comment: This answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470015/html5-iframe-no-scrolling/18470016#18470016 , if you cant add the class, just change `.className` to `iframe` in the CSS ...

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
<style>
    .noscroll{width:200px; height:200px; overflow-y: hidden;}
</style>

<iframe src="http://microsoft.com" class="noscroll" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: I cannot add a class to the iframe code as mentioned above.