# GWT - hide horizontal scroll bar

Tags: css, gwt

I am wondering... Is there a way to hide horizontal scroll bar with GWT standard [ScrollPane](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ScrollPanel.html)? *I mean maybe not using outer CSS styles etc?* Or you can recommend a more optimal way to achieve the effect?

...And concerning the CSS, right now I tried to set style like this for my ScrollPane

```
.a-scroll {
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

... but it seems it doesn't work and horizontal scrollbar is still visible :S So is there a workaround?

Thanks

Comment: Are you interested in *always* hide the horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: @Andrea Boscolo you are right. I want hide horizontal but have vertical shown only;

Comment: When you are setting that style are you setting a name for it in the code so it picks up the CSS class '.a-scroll'?

Comment: @Terrell Plotzki, of course, I do set it as a style name for my ScrollPanel but it gives no effect :S

Comment: Are you using `setStylePrimaryName` or `setStyleName`?

Comment: @Terrell Plotzki I am using setStyleName("a-scroll");

Comment: Are you removing all styles first? From the GWT Documentation:

_You should normally use_ `setStylePrimaryName(String)` _unless you wish to explicitly remove all existing styles._

Comment: @Terrell Plotzki I thought the setStyleName("a-scroll"); should override previous styles, is it?

Comment: Not according to the docs. You may want to inspect the DOM using firebug in firefox or Chrome developer tools to see what styles are being applied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default the `ScrollPanel`'s `overflow` property is set to `auto` (i.e., the scrollbar will appear as needed) to obtain the most cross-browser solution. So it's up to the browser to decide when to display such scrollbars. Also, calling `scrollPanel.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(false)` is useless since is already called at construction time (in the `initialize()` method).

Anyway I found that what you are requesting is a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3712).

If you want to *always* hide the horizontal scrollbar you need to set the `overflow-x: hidden` property on the scrollable element of the `ScrollPanel` (as you tried, but such panel is not a simple div with an `overflow` property on it). Try with:

```
public class MyScrollPanel extends ScrollPanel {

  public void setAlwaysHideHorizontalScrollBar(boolean alwaysHide) {
    getScrollableElement().getStyle().setOverflowX(alwaysHide ? Overflow.HIDDEN : Overflow.AUTO);
  }
  // ... and the like.
}
```

Remember that, if you set the above, in some browsers you will not be able to scroll horizontally anymore. Also `overflow-x/y` are CSS3 properties, while `overflow` is CSS2. So this might not be what you are after.

In such case some CSS tricks can help in order to hide the scrollbar but still allowing to scroll, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820304/hidden-scrollbars-in-firefox-allows-scrolling-but-just-no-scrollbar).

Anothe option could be using the `CustomScrollPanel` widget which allows, among other things, to hide the scrollbars by providing a, say, custom scrollbar with a zero-opacity style (not the best thing, tough).

Of course, another option could be to roll out your own div-based widget (maybe extending `SimplePanel`) with all the styles you need, as suggested in the issue.

Comment: OK thank you. I'll try the solution a little bit later and report you my results

Answer (score 1):

Probably a little cheap, but the vertical bar width is added to the widget's width, which means the widget no longer displays fully. Hence the horizontal bar showing so you can scroll to see the stuff hidden via the vertical scroll bar.

If you go

```
scrollPanel.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(false);
scrollPanel.setWidth("normalwidth + 8px");
```

it should stop showing.

Answer (score -1):

You can hide scrollbars if the content does not overflow the container using

`scrollPanel.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(false);`

If your scrollbars are still showing you may want to look at your content.

Comment: No, I want to have overflow-y supported to scroll it vertically only

Comment: This isn't even what that method is meant for. It's meant for configuring scrollbar display on touch devices.