# How to scroll a Div without a scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to scroll vertically a div without using scrollbar instead using only mousewheel up and down for scroll ?

I have a instance like ,

```
<div style="height:200px">
<div class="samplediv" style="overflow:scroll;overflow-y:hidden;height:1000px">
.
.
.
.    
</div>
</div>
```

such that bigger div lies inside the smaller div , i want to scroll up as well as down the inner div , but i wanna hide my vertical scroll , is that possible in anyway , i tried with event hooks for scroll , but event is not hooked.

Comment: Apart from the fact if it can or cannot be done it's not really a good practice.

Comment: Nobody tell him! Protect the standards. ;)

Comment: @CaptainCarl is correct. Users rely on the presence of a scrollbar to indicate that they can indeed scroll. You can perhaps alter the appearance of a scrollbar so that it fades when the div in question is not hovered over. Either way, it's a fair bit of CSS (quite possibly JS) trickery.

Comment: @captaincarl yes i know, the real thing is that i have a common scrollbar for two divs , i used to hook an event for the other div using the other div's scroll bar , but when i mousewheel up an down on the div having no scroll bar , it does looks wierd .thats why i got stucked .

Comment: @joe_Benito Sorry guys , this is what you need but http://jsfiddle.net/7vbPh/1/

Comment: @bharathRallapalli that was really elegant and helpfull

Comment: @joe_Benito Ohhhh Damn it I could have added an answer :P , Thanks anyway

Comment: Upvoted this question. With smartphone/tablet browsing, scrollbars are superfluous. Perhaps let question needs an answers that is up-to-date with current tech.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Please don't do this!** It will make the interface unusable because no one will no where the can scroll!

But if you must...

[How to Hide Your Scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5823379/1669208)

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qqPcb/)

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    width: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}

#scroller {
    width: 170px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: yellow;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="scroller">
        foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>
        foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>
        foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>foo<br>bar<br>baz<br>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes i know the difficult on interface but i have a scroll bar in common for two divs , that was the problem , but i got your resource useful , and also i'm aware of standards you said ;)

Comment: Your comment made things clearer. I would have put that in the question. :)