# Hiding the scroll bar in MS Edge and Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, scrollbar, microsoft-edge

I have a scrollable menu, which needs to be scrollable. I hide the scroll bar in Chrome by using:

```
.menu::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

Which works. What is the same for Firefox and MS Edge that will do the same?

Thanks

Comment: Probably everyone that is on this page is looking for `-ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;`. Someone should at least link to a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

What about overflow-y: auto? That should show the scrollbar only when the menu is longer than the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to hide scrollbars is with `overflow: hidden;`, you can still scroll with a mouse's scroll-wheel or trackpad scroll gesture, or by setting the element's scroll properties with JavaScript.

Comment: In MS Edge and Firefox this does not work. Menu goes down the page. I've tried...

overflow-y: hidden;  AND overflow: hidden;  But neither does the trick.

Comment: @Shocker_33 Please post a jsFiddle

Comment: Here is the [website](http://www.luucc.co.uk)

Comment: this is just plain wrong. you can't still scroll.

Answer (score 0):

On your website, when I open IE's F12 pane and select `<div class="menu...">` and change `overflow-y: scroll;` to `overflow-y: none;` it renders as you want it.

You don't need webkit-specific rules at all.

Comment: But this stops the user from scrolling the menu when the viewpoint is smaller than the length of the menu. Hence why in my question i stated that it needs to scroll.